# TypeError: f0() takes 1 positional argument but 9 were given

Tags: python, django

Suppose i have a list:

```
a=['hello.com','ok.com']
```

i have two function:

```
   def f0(id):
         try:
             model.objects.get(links=id)
         except:
             model(modelfield=id).save()

   def f1(request):
        for i in a:
             t1=thread.Thread(target=f0,args=(i))
             t1.start()
```

While i try to run this on my server , its giving me error .

```
  TypeError: f0() takes 1 positional argument but 9 were given
```

Kindly tell me whats the problem .

Comment: not quite sure,but looks like the loop is going through a first element(hello.com) which has 9 letters,are you sure a is a list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are passing in a single string as the `args` value:

```
args=(i)
```

That's not a tuple, that's a grouped expression containing just `'hello.com'`, an iterable with 9 separate elements (single-character strings).

Add a comma; tuples are formed by the comma, not the parentheses (although you need parentheses to disambiguate the tuple from other arguments in a call):

```
args=(i,)
```

or if you find that confusing, use a list:

```
args=[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

In 'args=(i)', (i) is not a tuple.
Convert (i) into a tuple by appending , so the right statement will be:
     t1=thread.Thread(target=f0,args=(i,))